# Handle datetime checks during SQL Server day light savings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

- We have a logging table that has entry added every minute (log_date field in the table is
  logged in UTC, the server local time is in PST) and we have a
  condition that monitors and alerts if there is no entry in the table
  in last 15 minutes.
- Logging table is logged with data using a SQL Agent job scheduled to run every minute.
- When the DST is turned off we have received false alerts, how to
  handle this situation while checking last 15 minutes data?
- We are currently on SQL Server 2019 and the log_date is of type
  datetime2.

[image]

Added table definition and query used to populate the table using SQL agent job.

```
create table latency_log(
        [log_date] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
        [replica_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
        [log_send_queue_size] [bigint] NULL,
        [log_send_rate] [bigint] NULL,
        [redo_queue_size] [bigint] NULL,
        [redo_rate] [bigint] NULL
)

insert into latency_log
select
    GETUTCDATE() as log_date,
    ar.replica_id,
    hdrs.log_send_queue_size,
    hdrs.log_send_rate,
    hdrs.redo_queue_size,
    hdrs.redo_rate
from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states hdrs 
join sys.availability_replicas ar on hdrs.replica_id = ar.replica_id
```

Condition that monitors the logging:

```
declare @since datetime2 = dateadd(MINUTE,-15,getutcdate())
if exists ( 
    select top 1 1 
    from latency_log
    where log_date > @since
)
    select 'No alert'
else
    select 'Alert'
```

I don't find any runs missing from the SQL agent job [history](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sazrUHPYcP_iYiel3Bo9FV9rg-yWdIcXdfKOFnamNcY/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: You said that `log_date` is in UTC, but the screenshot shows `log_date` being affected by a DST time shift. UTC is doesn't change for DST. Are you sure that column is UTC?

Comment: The logging is happening via SQL Server Agent job, where the local time zone is PST. I will add that information to my original question

Comment: So, the `log_date` column is **not** UTC. Which contradicts this point in your question: "log_date field in the table is logged in UTC"

Comment: the type of the field is defined as datetime2, but the value being inserted to it is by calling getutcdate() function.

Comment: Can you include the query you're using to return the records in your screenshot?

Comment: Added to the original post.

Comment: "we have a condition that monitors and alerts" you'll also need to post this code.

Comment: Added details to the original post.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that [this post by Paul Randal](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-does-daylight-savings-time-affect-disaster-recovery/) explains the issue you are seeing:

> Well, it’s not so common knowledge that at the end of DST when the clocks go back an hour (always at 02:00 in the U.S.), SQL Agent essentially pauses for an hour (in at least SQL Server 2000 onward).

It suggests that, if you check the job history, you will see a gap of an hour when the clocks go back.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, but I don't find any miss when looked at agent job history. Added complete job run history for that day to my original post.